# Different behavior with and without pyinstaller --noconsole

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working a window GUI minitool with Python3, tkinter and MySQL

At first, the code works perfectly fine with running in VS Code Python Terminal.
Then I move on to use pyinstaller to pack the source files to .exe

Everything still fine at this stage.

Trying to get rid of the console, I add --noconsole to pyinstaller and something weird happens.
The GUI stop working just before execute and commit to database.

By adding tkinter.messagebox, I can located that the program stop working anymore before or after I assign a MySQL cmd with string.format().

But if I remove the --noconsole argument, everything returns to normal

What could be the issue here?

---

Edited for code sample:

without --noconsole, both messagebox pop-up. But with it, 2nd mbox never pop-up

```
if A == True:
    tk.mbox('Debug 1')
    query1 = "__some_SQL_query__'".format('__some_values')
    tk.mbox('Debug 2')
    result = execute_query(query1,....)
else:
    ....
```

Comment: does anything get shown in the console? if so well then obviously you need console and you can't not use it

Comment: @Matiiss I do have 1 print() before the string assignment, but it doesn't seems the issue because I also have a few print() at the start of the application.
Even I comment all print() in the code, I still had no progress on the same position

Comment: Ok, but can you see stuff that shows up in console when running the console, like does anything get shown? Also, you said sth about executing a cmd command, how exactly do you do that? It could be that to execute that cmd command using whatever method you are using, you simply need to have the console, maybe try using `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: @Matiiss I have added that part of code above, where installed with --noconsole, it never get pass the query.format. It simply stops without popping 'Debug2' with no indications

Comment: But when not adding the option, both messagebox popup accordingly, and can execute the SQL successfully.

Comment: have you tried using some other formatting options like `f strings`?, otherwise it is kinda weird